# How to enter form data into a database using Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I want to get form data using ajax and then submit it to my php page which will then insert it in my database. On successful insert I want to display "you have been registered successfully" and on fail "Failed to register" and in case you are already a member I display "Already a member just Sign in".

For some reason my my ajax code is not working as I expect. It's jumping to the last part (else statement without even caring about the if statements). My php code is correct. Because I have tested it alone and it's working fine.

Can someone suggest for me a solution or another way to accomplish this **keeping in mind I don't want to go to another page.**

Here is my JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function){
    //Signup Js
    $("#Register").click(function(){ //#Register is my submit button id
        var action = $("#sp-form").attr('action'); //#sp-form is the register form id.
        var spform_data = {
            myusername: $("#myusername").val(),
            myemail: $("#myemail").val(),
            mypassword: $("#mypassword").val() //Getting data from the input forms using their respective id's
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: action,
            data: spform_data,
            success: function(outcome)
            {
                if(outcome == "success"){
                    $("#sp-form").slideUp('slow', function(){
                        $("#message_sp").html('<p class="success">You have been registered successfully!</p><p style="color:#1c1c1c;">Redirecting....</p>');
                    });
                }
                else if(outcome == "alreadymember") {
                    $("#modal_signup").css("height","380");
                    $("#message_sp").html('<p class="error">ERROR: Email match found,Just Sign in.</p>');
                }
                else if(outcome == "failed"){
                    $("#modal_signup").css("height","380");
                    $("#message_sp").html('<p class="error">ERROR:  Failed to Register</p>');
                }
                else{
                    $("#modal_signup").css("height","380");
                    $("#message_sp").html('<p class="error">ERROR:  Unknown   ERROR</p>');
                }                
            }            
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

And here is my PHP/MySQLi code

```
<?php
if ($_POST)
{
    $host = "localhost";
    $user= "root";
    $password = " ";

    try {
        $conn = mysqli_connect($host , $user , $password) or die("unable to connect to Local Host"); //Establishing connection with the server
        $sql = mysqli_select_db($conn,'audacity') or die("unable to connect to database"); //selecting a database from the server #after connecting
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['myusername']);
    $mail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['myemail']);
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['mypassword']);

    // Query of SQL
    $Query =mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO  registration (Username,Email,Password) VALUES ('$name', '$mail' , '$pass')")) //if successful outcome is true
    if($Query ==true){
        echo "success";
    }
    elseif ($Query==false) {  #if failed
        $sqlbd = "SELECT Email FROM registration WHERE Email='$mail' ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlbd);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){  //possible rsn for failure
            echo "alreadymember";             
        }
        else{
            echo "failed";  //unknown reason.
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Where is the problem

Comment: insert console.log(outcome) at first line of success function and see what is going on in your console browser.

Comment: Do you see any changes in your database?

Comment: No.. No changes in my database

Comment: Than your problem is probably in you php file. Does the page return any errormessages of errorheaders?

Comment: The problem is you must use firebug tool to debug your php code.

Comment: Hey @Jasper when i click the submit button... It's not even submitting..

Comment: Jasper... I am not seeing any changes in my database because my submit button when I click it its not submitting the data... It's like it's frozen

Comment: Ok.. Panupog i will try firebug

Comment: Thanks guys it now works

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion... @Panupong Kongarn i didn't know what firebug tool is but you will teach me someday 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to check if num_rows is ==1 in the beggining of your ifs statements...Your php just enter email then check num rows as an else statement...you first check num rows then set if statements Or you have setted unique to your email column?

Comment: Yeah primary key is email

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that your code has a number of errors.
I am attaching a corrected version of the codes; however, I will assume (from the php code) that the objective is to prevent multiple registration; if that is the case, your logic should be checked. You inserted before checking, so the checking code will never be run, ever. So do the checking before attempting to insert. The overall code doesn't seem okay.
I only fixed the errors, you should work on the logic.

JQuery
    $(document).ready(function () {

```
            $("#sp-form").submit(function (e) {
                return false;
            });
            $("#Register").click(function () {
                var action = $("#sp-form").attr('action'); //#sp-form 
is the register form id.

                var spform_data = {
                    myusername: $("#myusername").val(),
                    myemail: $("#myemail").val(),
                    mypassword: $("#mypassword").val()         
//Getting data from the input forms using their respective id's
                }


                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: action,
                    data: spform_data,
                    success: function (outcome)
                    {
                        if (outcome.indexOf("success")>=0) {
                            $("#sp-form").slideUp('slow', function () {
                                $("#message_sp").html('<p 
class="success">You have been registered successfully!</p><p 
style="color:#1c1c1c;">Redirecting....</p>');
                            });
                        }
                        else if (outcome.indexOf("alreadymember")>=0) {


                            $("#modal_signup").css("height", "380");
                            $("#message_sp").html('<p 
class="error">ERROR: Email match found,Just Sign in.</p>');


                        }

                        else if (outcome.indexOf("failed")>=0) {


                            $("#modal_signup").css("height", "380");
                            $("#message_sp").html('<p 
class="error">ERROR:  Failed to Register</p>');


                        }
                        else {


                            $("#modal_signup").css("height", "380");
                            $("#message_sp").html('<p 
class="error">Unknown Error</p>');
                        }

                    }

                });
                return false;


            });
        });

// Php
 $host = "localhost";
        $user = "root";
        $password = "";
        $conn = "";
        try {
            $conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password) or 
die("unable to connect to Local Host"); //Establishing connection with 
the server

            $sql = mysqli_select_db($conn, 'audacity') or die("unable 
to connect to database"); //selecting a database from the server #after 
connecting
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }


        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['myusername']);
        $mail = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['myemail']);
        $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mypassword']);

        // Query of SQL


        $Query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO  registration 
(Username,Email,Password) VALUES ('$name', '$mail' , '$pass')"); //if 
successful outcome is true
        if ($Query == true) {

            echo "success";
        } elseif ($Query == false) {  #if failed
            $sqlbd = "SELECT Email FROM registration WHERE 
Email='$mail' ";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlbd);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {  //possible rsn for 
failure
                echo "alreadymember";
            } else {

                echo "failed";  //unknown reason.
            }
        }

        mysqli_close($conn);
    }
```

Comment: Yah Oluasa i inserted before checking because I realized if you insert and a match is found in the database.. Your data won't be inserted since email is the primary key

Comment: But thanks alot I will compare your logic and mine and I adjust where necessary... Thanks bro don't delete your comment

Comment: Okay, I do understand. Never the less, you should put the check before the insert, so if the record is not found, then you can insert. Its cleaner.

Comment: Ok I will put before